# Python debugger (pdb) encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following problem with python while in debug mode via pdb.

It seems that python in the debug mode works with different charset than the normal mode. I'll try to explain better in the following points:

- In debug mode, I get the following results

```
(pdb) "ó"
'\xa2'
(pdb) (u"ó")
u'\xa2'
(pdb) print u"ó"
¢
```

- While in normal mode I get the following

```
>>> "ó"
'\xa2'
>>> u"ó"
u'\xf3'
>>> print u"ó"
ó
```

Both modes seem to encode in cp858, while debug mode seems to decode with cp1252 codec (which is the one I explicitly stated with `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-`), and normal mode seems do decode in cp858. We can see evidence of this in the following results:

```
>>> '\xa2'.decode("cp858")
u'\xf3'
>>> '\xa2'.decode("cp1252")
u'\xa2'
```

The importance of the problem is that, in debug mode, I can't see the value of objects that have unicode strings (I'm using pandas, so all of my objects) Do you know how can I force the debugger to use the same codec for encoding and for decoding strings? All I get in debug mode are errors about strings not matching.

NOTES: I am running the program from the console via the command `python -i mycode.py`.